# WPF XAML Encoding Error

Tags: wpf, xaml, encoding

I opened Login.XAML file in VS2012, it showing Encoding dialog box shown below
[image]

After clicking OK
[image]

I didn't see any design content of mine. I googled out but I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking the encoding, or by something done previously, you've put in a character that Unicode or windows doesn't recognize. Scour your code or click on the error and you should find out how to fix it.